# Resampling hourly data to 6 hours

Tags: python, pandas

```
              Timestamp                  Value
0   2017-11-22 09:00:00                 12.356965
1   2017-11-22 10:00:00                 26.698426
2   2017-11-22 11:00:00                 13.153104
3   2017-11-22 12:00:00                 15.425182
4   2017-11-22 13:00:00                 15.161085
5   2017-11-22 14:00:00                 17.038580
6   2017-11-22 15:00:00                 11.035375
7   2017-11-22 16:00:00                  5.208686
8   2017-11-22 17:00:00                  6.026359
9   2017-11-22 18:00:00                  6.259712
10  2017-11-22 19:00:00                 21.792882
11  2017-11-22 20:00:00                  9.053889
```

Let say, above is my dataframe, i need to resample the data for 6 hours, so for 9:00, the value should be average of data from 9,10,11,12,13,14..
Similarly for 10, the value should be average of data from 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15... and so on.......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rolling.mean`:

```
df.set_index('Timestamp').rolling('6h').mean()

                         Value
Timestamp                     
2017-11-22 09:00:00  12.356965
2017-11-22 10:00:00  19.527696
2017-11-22 11:00:00  17.402832
2017-11-22 12:00:00  16.908419
2017-11-22 13:00:00  16.558952
2017-11-22 14:00:00  16.638890
2017-11-22 15:00:00  16.418625
2017-11-22 16:00:00  12.837002
2017-11-22 17:00:00  11.649211
2017-11-22 18:00:00  10.121633
2017-11-22 19:00:00  11.226932
2017-11-22 20:00:00   9.896151
```

---

Alternative using `asfreq` + `rolling.mean` + `shift`:

```
df.set_index('Timestamp').asfreq('h').rolling(6).mean().shift(-5)

                         Value
Timestamp                     
2017-11-22 09:00:00  16.638890
2017-11-22 10:00:00  16.418625
2017-11-22 11:00:00  12.837002
2017-11-22 12:00:00  11.649211
2017-11-22 13:00:00  10.121633
2017-11-22 14:00:00  11.226932
2017-11-22 15:00:00   9.896150
2017-11-22 16:00:00        NaN
2017-11-22 17:00:00        NaN
2017-11-22 18:00:00        NaN
2017-11-22 19:00:00        NaN
2017-11-22 20:00:00        NaN
```

The result is the same as before, but shifted by 5 places.

Comment: I don't think, this is giving proper results..as for 9th hour, the value remains same, for 10th hour, it's not the mean of 10 to 15th hour..
Rolling mean takes the mean of previous entries, for 10th hour, if rolling('6h') is given, it takes average of previous 6 hours...i hope you understand my problem

Comment: @SatyajitPattnaik The values are as you want them, but they are displaced by 6 rows. For example, the mean for 6-14 will be in the 6th row.

Comment: @Coldspeed, thanks for it, this is what i was looking for, thanks again :)

Comment: @Coldspeed, last question, can your query be enhanced so that my last 5 entries are not shown as NaN, may be for 16th hour, value to be average of (16,17,18,19,20), for 17th hour value as avg(17,18,19,20) and so on till 20th hour having value of 20th hour itself..

Comment: @SatyajitPattnaik It's possible but ugly... you will need to reverse and then compute the rolling window: `df.set_index('Timestamp').asfreq('h')[::-1].rolling(6, min_periods=1).mean()[::-1]`